# rigify buttons problem

Tags: rigging

So I created rig bones and etc, but I still can't properly generate rigify buttons, when I press *Generate Rig*

[image] ,

rig bones of my character goes somewhere down. How can I fix this? [image]

Comment: Hi. Have you applied the scale to your model (Ctrl+A in Object Mode)?

Comment: Before pressing the generate button apply the scale of your Metarig also (Ctrl A).